# Automatic resize in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, resize, windowbuilder

Currently I am developing a GUI using Java (Window Builder) and it looks like this so far:
http://imageshack.com/a/img843/4818/75no.png

The problem is, when I maximize it, all the graphical objects stay focused in the left upper corner: http://imageshack.com/a/img713/5349/g7iz.png

I've already made some searches in order to discover how to automatically resize and/or change the locations of these graphical objects, but I could not find anything. Sorry if the solution for this is easy, but I am still a newbie in Java.

Comment: Find the Swing layout tutorial and ditch the Window Builder.

Comment: That's what happens when you use a Window Builder: you don't learn how GUI code works and you are unable to solve problems related to the GUI yourself :)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) Provide ASCII art (or an image with a simple drawing) of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Answer (score 0):

You start by using [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

> I am still a newbie in Java.

And don't forget to click on the "trail (ie. table of contents)" link to find information about all the basic Swing features.